# How to add a breakpoint to a public field that is serializable?

Tags: c#

I have a field in a class that is serialzed:

```
[OptionalField(VersionAdded = 2)]
public bool IsUser;
```

From what I understand, both private fields and properties are not serialized correct?

I want to put a breakpoint to see how the property IsUser is modified throughout the page request, how can I do this while still maintaining that the field is serialized as it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first assumption is generally not correct. Is does depend upon the serializer though. For something marked with the [Serializable Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx), this *should* hold:

> > All the public *and private* fields in a type that are marked by the SerializableAttribute are serialized by default,

To add a breakpoint, create a setter/getter wrapping the value and add the break-point to the assignment in the setter.

Happy coding.

Comment: @codecompleting The Serializable Attribute applies to the Type (class). To have it not serialize the field the field must be annotated with NonSearialized Attribute.